# static versus dynamic equilibrium when bending over

Tags: neurology, human-ear

When a person stoops/bends over, is the equilibrium functioning static equilibrium or dynamic equilibrium? I am not sure, because on the one hand the person is not moving (static), however, his/her head is moving (dynamic).

Thank you!